# How to add random and/or fixed effects into cloglog regression in R

Tags: r, regression, fixed, glm, random-effects

**Update question on treatment of one variable for fixed effects**
I am planning to run a cloglog regression in R with random and/or fixed effects to check for unobserved heterogeneity. Now i have not found anything on how to do this in R only one function in Stata. Is anyone familiar with this? 
**I have a variable zipcode  which i would like to enter, this variable consists of 205 levels and i am kind of stuck on what to do.**

This is an example of my cloglog regression:

```
    model_simple <- as.formula("completion_yesno ~  ac + ov + UCRate + FirstWeek + LastWeek + DayofWeekSu + DayofWeekMo + DayofWeekTu + DayofWeekWe + DayofWeekTh + DayofWeekFr + MonthofYearJan + MonthofYearFeb + MonthofYearMar + MonthofYearApr +MonthofYearMay+ MonthofYearJun + MonthofYearJul + MonthofYearAug + MonthofYearSep + MonthofYearOct + MonthofYearNov")
clog_simple1 = glm(model_simple,data=cllw,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
summary(clog_simple1)
```

I have tried to enter fixed effects with the glmmboost function from the package glmmML package

```
> model_simple <- as.formula("completion_yesno ~  ac + ov +
> UCRate + FirstWeek + LastWeek + DayofWeekSu + DayofWeekMo
> + DayofWeekTu + DayofWeekWe + DayofWeekTh + DayofWeekFr + MonthofYearJan + MonthofYearFeb + MonthofYearMar + MonthofYearApr
> +MonthofYearMay+ MonthofYearJun + MonthofYearJul + MonthofYearAug + MonthofYearSep + MonthofYearOct + MonthofYearNov") clog_fe <-
> glmmboot(model_simple, data=cllw,family = binomial(link = cloglog),
> cluster = zip, boot = 5000) summary(clog_fe)
```

The function just runs and never seems to come to an result.
I am stuck and happy for every tip.

Comment: check out [`pglm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/pglm.pdf) it might have what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fit fixed-effects model with the standard `glm` function. You just need to create a dummy by level of interest. For instance, something in this flavor:

## Fixed effects

```r
model_FE <- as.formula("completion_yesno ~ factor(groupvar) + ac + ov + UCRate + FirstWeek + LastWeek + DayofWeekSu + DayofWeekMo + DayofWeekTu + DayofWeekWe + DayofWeekTh + DayofWeekFr + MonthofYearJan + MonthofYearFeb + MonthofYearMar + MonthofYearApr +MonthofYearMay+ MonthofYearJun + MonthofYearJul + MonthofYearAug + MonthofYearSep + MonthofYearOct + MonthofYearNov")
glm(model_simple,data=cllw,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
```

`factor(group)` will create K-1 (or K if you want to fit the model without intercept) coefficients.

## Random effects

You must use another package `lme4` that proposes a function for that `glmer`. You can find some information [here](https://www.jaredknowles.com/journal/2013/11/25/getting-started-with-mixed-effect-models-in-r) and [here](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/r/fixedRandom3)